# Stop Screen From AutoRotating, but Keep UIWebView Rotation

Tags: ios, uiwebview, rotation

I have a UIWebView in my viewcontroller that is embedding a YouTube video and when the user clicks it, it plays the video. I want the webview to be able to rotate, but not the viewcontroller that it's being held on. Are there any solutions out there for this problem? This is an iOS6 and above supported application.

Comment: Do you want only one screen to rotate which has UIWebView in it ??

Comment: No, well the uiwebview opens to a movie player when clicked by the user, I want that to autorotate, not the screen it's on.

Answer (score 0):

In your `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method, change the UIWebView to the new orientation, then return NO.

This way the view controller will stay the way it is, but you can do whatever you need to do to the UIWebView to make it display correctly in the new orientation.

Comment: Are there any coding examples of this?